# Use web.config in another project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm working on a visual studio solution which was developed by others long time ago. It is for asp.net 2. Now, need to add some new features.

In the solution, it has several projects, including myProject.Data, myProject.Business, ..., myProject.Website . Over time, different developers made the changes.

In the myProject.Data, it defines a SQL server connection string as a constant, and use it do some SQL work. This is used in myProject.Website. In the myProject.Website, it also reads some files from a network drive, and do some processing too.

Now, I develop it on my local, not in the company's environment, so I can not access to the network drive, and the sql will be my local sql express. In this case, is there a good way to configure this, so that, I can simply change a configuration, and it will compile the code for my development environment or for the production?

In the myProject.Website, I could add a app key for the development environment, so that it will read the files from my local instead of network drive. However, the question is: how can I read this key in myProject.Data ?

Or, is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

> Now, I develop it on my local, not in the company's environment, so I can not access to the network drive, and the sql will be my local sql express. In this case, is there a good way to configure this, so that, I can simply change a configuration, and it will compile the code for my development environment or for the production?

Normally, connecting to database should be done using a connection string which is configurable. So you should have (or define) a configurable key in web.config to represent database connection string and connect using that. Furthermore, note that this way, changing the web.config won't "compile" anything and the changes should take effect without the need to rebuild the project. see [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_configuration.htm) (section connection string)

> In the myProject.Website, I could add a app key for the development environment, so that it will read the files from my local instead of network drive. However, the question is: how can I read this key in myProject.Data ?

You cannot read the configuration of another project that easily (unless its a class library which is being used in that project or you are willing to read and parse that xml file!) but what's wrong with redefining that key in the second project?

Generally I think you did not understood web.config's concept very well. So following a good tutorial like [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_configuration.htm) may help you master it. Good luck.

Comment: thanks for replying. I totally understand the web.config. This is a very old project, I'm trying to figure out a way to make this simple without changing too much since it does not pay. :)